# Unable to execute dotnet run comman

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core

When I am inside the project directory and try to run:

```
donet run
```

then I get following errors:

```
Startup.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Localdb' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/ubuntu/Pranjal/Pranjal.csproj]
Startup.cs(11,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Pomelo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/ubuntu/Pranjal/Pranjal.csproj]
Startup.cs(17,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestCore' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/ubuntu/Pranjal/Pranjal.csproj]
```

My startup.cs file is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Localdb;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using TestCore;

namespace Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        //public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        //{
        //    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        //}
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services
                .AddDbContextPool<PistisContext>( // replace "YourDbContext" with the class name of your DbContext
                options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PistisEntities"), // replace with your Connection String
                    mySqlOptions =>
                    {
                        mySqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(5, 7, 17), ServerType.MySql); // replace with your Server Version and Type
                    }

            ));

            //services.AddDbContextPool<PistisContext>(options =>
            //    options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PistisEntities")));
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("EnableCORS", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials().Build();
                });
            });
            services
                .AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddJsonOptions(Options =>
            {
            //      Options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver
            //= new DefaultContractResolver();
            var resolver = Options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver;
            if (resolver != null)
                (resolver as DefaultContractResolver)
                    .NamingStrategy = null;
            });

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.Run(async (context) =>
     {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World from my little app!");
       });
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            //app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());
            //app.UseCors(options =>
            //options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
            //.AllowAnyMethod()
            //.AllowAnyHeader());
            app.UseCors("EnableCORS");
            app.UseMvc();
        }


    }
}
```

and my Pranjal.csproject is as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Generally when I run the dotnet run it starts normally but after adding Program.cs file it just stop working.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all the referenced dlls next to the application? Specifically:

- Localdb
- Pomelo
- TestCore

Also in the ItemGroup section of your .csproj you are missing the above package references.